# Kafka Consumer with TestContainers in Integration Test

Tags: asp.net-core, apache-kafka, integration-testing, testcontainers

In my project, I have Test containers for the Kafka Integration Test. I can produce messages and consume them. For consuming I have a Kafka consumer that follows a CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation) pattern. Instead of directly asserting a return value from the consumer, I use a handler that subscribes to a Kafka topic and reacts to incoming messages. The challenge is that I can't directly assert the results of the handler's actions since there's no return value. So, how do I effectively test this Kafka consumer in an integration test

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a library for asyncronous awaits, like [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/), and would assert that the processing of the messages lead to the results you wanted.

Here's for example a part of the test that we use in the [testcontainers/workshop](https://github.com/testcontainers/workshop/blob/main/step-7-test-the-api.md):

```
 given(requestSpecification)
                .body(new Rating(talkId, 5))
                .when()
                .post("/ratings")
                .then()
                .statusCode(202);

        await().untilAsserted(() -> {
            given(requestSpecification)
                    .queryParam("talkId", talkId)
                    .when()
                    .get("/ratings")
                    .then()
                    .body("5", is(1));
        });
```

It uses RestAssured to trigger a POST query, that will set in motion the processing, including talking via Kafka. You can set up the messages in any other way as well.

Then Awaitility.await will run the code repeatedly (you can configure delays, timeouts, etc), until a condition is met. In our case, the value of the ratings are visible on a different endpoint. (In the business logic of the app they propagate there via Kafka.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thank you for your answer but this is not what I wanted. You mentioned that waiting for the request for response.  In my case, there is no request.  I can publish the message to Kafka. but I need to know how my handler handled the subscribed event. In the awaitilty examples, we need to create a new object but in the integration test, there is already an object that listens to the event because the whole project is running.

Comment: I meant this more as an illustration. In general your test flow is: 
1. Publish message to Kafka. 2. Await the sideeffects of message processing.